# Monit fails to execute the complete command in start program

Tags: syslog, monit

I'm using monit 5.4 on Mac 10.7.4 machine. When i tried to execute a example configuration

```
check process syslogd with pidfile /var/run/syslogd.pid
   start program = "/etc/init.d/sysklogd start"
   stop program = "/etc/init.d/sysklogd stop"
   if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

from [monit wiki page](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples#syslogd), I get the following error.

```
'syslogd' process is not running
'syslogd' trying to restart
'syslogd' start: /etc/init.d/sysklogd
'syslogd' failed to start
```

Monit does not take the complete command given in the "start program" of the monitrc file. It just takes the first word in the command and tries to execute it and fails. Is this a known issue? If yes, does it have a workaround? If not, what am i missing here and how to get it working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (from http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/FAQ#execution)

```
start program = "/bin/bash -c '/etc/init.d/blah start'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `/etc/init.d/sysklogd` actually exist?

On 10.8 I have `/etc/init.d/syslog` and manually running `/etc/init.d/syslog restart` works fine.